# How do I get IntelliJ IDEA code completion to import static Java methods as Kotlin top level functions?

Tags: intellij-idea, static, code-completion, kotlin

IntelliJ IDEA code completion suggests static Java methods when editing Kotlin code but it imports the Java class instead of the static method as a top level function (see [Function Scope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#function-scope)).

e.g. Typing "chrome" and pressing `Enter` adds `import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities` and replaces "chrome" with "DesiredCapabilities.chrome()" instead of adding `import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities.chrome` and leaving "chrome" as "chrome".

How do I get IntelliJ IDEA code completion to import static Java methods as top level functions?

Comment: FYI: I've now also created [IDEA-148872](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148872).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a bug in [IntelliJ IDEA's issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues), [IDEA-148872](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148872), and Dmitry Jemerov (Principal Engineer [at JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/company/people/)) converted it to a feature: [KT-10277](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10277).

As such I gather that this is not yet implemented so the answer is you currently cannot "get IntelliJ IDEA code completion to import static Java methods as Kotlin top level functions".

You can check/watch [KT-10277](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10277) to see updates on it being implemented.